# How to delete Tomcat Access Log after n days?

Tags: tomcat, logging

I only would like to keep the Access Logs of the last n days created by Tomcat Access Log Valve.
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access%20Log%20Valve

But there seems to be no configuration-Attribute to define how long to keep the log-files? I guess this is because "Access Log Valve" only creates log files and doesn't delete them, is that correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default `rotatable` is true for Access Log, so you will be having a new file created every 24 hours.

Tomcat itself does not do any housekeeping on the old files, the general principle on a Unix system is to have a cron job set up on the system to archive older files into a back up directory and/or delete them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You confirmed my assumption, that files need to be deleted by a cronjob (or a visual basic script on windows).

Comment: How do you remove the old logs ? I did try to do it on modify time, but in some cases the log files have been modified by other process / users, and as such not removed in time ...

Comment: Preety old but, leaving the answer to the question if someone runs into this at some point.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962477/logrotate-files-with-date-in-the-file-name

Comment: This is not completely correct. Catalina supports a `maxDays` parameter. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Comment: @ValerioBozz Not true for acces logs - `maxDays` cannot be used there, because it does not use log4j for logging.

Answer (score 6):

For Tomcat 7 you can config `tomcat/conf/logging.properties`. Example:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 90
```

Note: that `1` is not a typo.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Note: this does not affect access log files, which are handled by the Access Log Valve, not by the main Tomcat (Apache Commons) logging.

Comment: This does not affect access log files, which are handled by the [Access Log Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Logging), not by the main Tomcat (Apache Commons) logging.

Comment: Thank you @SteveHart, I've updated the answer with your useful note.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows, based on Erwan's answer in [Tomcat localhost_access_log files cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886338/tomcat-localhost-access-log-files-cleanup/31903968#31903968), for the given folder and recursing into all subfolders:

```
forfiles /p "C:\path\to\httplogs\" /s /m *.log /d -10 /c "cmd /c del @PATH"
```

To test, just use:

```
forfiles /p "C:\path\to\httplogs\" /s /m *.log /d -10 /c "cmd /c dir /b @PATH"
```

And when having multiple suffixes in the log folder, like both `.txt` and `.log`, see [using FORFILES in batch to delete tmp and bak files older than a week](https://superuser.com/questions/650800/using-forfiles-in-batch-to-delete-tmp-and-bak-files-older-than-a-week/650805#650805):

```
for %%t in (.txt, .log) do forfiles /p "C:\path\to\httplogs\" /s /m *%%t /d -10 /c "cmd /c del @PATH"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to create logrotate config:

```
#cat /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat
/var/log/tomcat/*.log {
        su tomcat tomcat
        copytruncate  
        daily  
        rotate 6  
        compress  
        missingok
}
```

"su tomcat tomcat" - i added for avoiding logrotate error on wrong permissions

Answer (score 2):

Incase of Apache Tomcat 7.0. You can use maxDays parameter to delete old log files. 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html

Answer (score 2):

For tomcat 9 its part of access log configuration. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Logging:

> maxDays
> The maximum number of days rotated access logs will be retained for before being deleted. If not specified, the default value of -1 will be used which means never delete old files.

Answer (score 1):

If you use tomcat within spring boot you can use `server.tomcat.accesslog.max-days=3` to delete old files after e. g. 3 days.

A minimal working configuration with spring boot to log the accesslog would be:

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=C:/path/to/dir
server.tomcat.accesslog.max-days=3
```

References:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-logs
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/71df2f311b04462784a76ed0b9288f2d659a68eb/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-docs/src/main/asciidoc/appendix/application-properties.adoc

Answer (score 0):

run in terminal:

```
locate RELEASE-NOTES | egrep 'tomcat|apache' | xargs grep "Apache Tomcat Version"
```