# Does tomcat provide any log retention policy for request log generated by AccessLogValve?

Tags: tomcat

I recently start using `Tomcat 7.0.50` (I was using `jetty 9.2.2` before this). I am using `AccessLogValve` to log request logs. I want to retain only last few days of logs only. Jetty provide this by setting property `requestlog.retain` to desired value.

Do tomcat provide any such feature? (I know I can do this by writting some crons or some other code to delete old files, but I was wondering if this is already available as part of tomcat feature.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete Tomcat Access Log after n days?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772021/how-to-delete-tomcat-access-log-after-n-days)